# Flex uncontinuous linechart?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, charts

Is there a way to break the line in a line-chart, if the gap between 2 values on the x axis is bigger then a given value? For example there are 20 values but the first 13 are close to each other on the x axis and should be connected with a line, but the other 7 are a bit far from these and should be connected with another line. The type of values are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data points in a series will be connected by a line. To have a disconnected line just create a new series and split your datapoints into two groups. Both series will probably have the same `yField` value, just two different data sources.

The example at the bottom of the page shows the use of multiple series:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/series/LineSeries.html

And, for those who are interested, this example shows how to mix different types of charts together:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_11.html